# How to create Basic Cross Platform Application

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile

I am new to apps development, just wanted to learn HTML5 apps development using only CSS & HTML5 and Javascript.
I am eagerly waiting to know, how do I start, I mean what I have to follow to start it test it and deploy it on multiple apps store so that people can search & download my apps.

Comment: You can use Titanium or PhoneGap for that, but from my experience I would suggest you build the app's using native code, I already have a lot of problems using that kind of framework

Comment: cordova or adobe build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build cross platform applications, then you can start using sencha touch. Sencha Touch is a Javascript framework which is used to build cross platform applications using only HTML5, CSS3 and JAVASCRIPT.

Download the sdk and sencha cmd from the sencha website.
http://www.sencha.com/

Once your setup is ready you can go through the documentation which is excellent.
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#

Answer (score 0):

As GhostDerfel mentions, PhoneGap would be my choice.  However if you want to create the app native to android add a WebView that covers the layout and load the url or html data into it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html